# creating user input from the oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to ask the user which item they want to choose within a certain column named "SKU" and I want them to be able to type whichever item that is and it display the appropriate details from that table.

I know that to get user input you can:

```
  declare
  x number;
  begin
    x := &enter_value;
    dbms_output.put_line(x*2);
  end;
```

This only multiplies user input by 2 which is just an example. 
How would I start asking the user which item they want and then take that item and display everything that ties that item to the table "SKU"?

My thoughts:

```
 declare
 SELECT * FROM SKU
 WHERE SKU = x
 x number;
 begin
   x := &enter_the_sku;
   dbms_output.put_line(SKU);
 end;
```

Desired output: 
    I would like it to run as if I ran the code:

```
SELECT *
FROM SKU 
WHERE item = 234;
```

I understand this is not right at all because it doesn't run but if anyone has any idea as to how I can change this code to my desired output it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I know I can just run a select * from statement to get what I want but I am trying to learn PL/SQL.

Comment: Prompting for input is a feature of whatever client tool you are using, not the PL/SQL language. Answers will depend on what tool that is.

Comment: Thank you for the insight William, I apologize for not making my question not clearer as I am still learning the language. So, If our company was using Java, does that count as a client tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply receive user input while running  the SQL .

```
SELECT *
FROM SKU 
WHERE item = &item ;
```

if you want to run a PL/SQL block to retrieve result, you may use a stored procedure and `REFCURSOR` bind variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE pr_getcu
     (p_ITEM IN SKU.item%TYPE,  p_query OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) AS
    BEGIN
      OPEN p_query FOR SELECT *
      FROM SKU 
     WHERE item = p_ITEM ;
    END;
    /

VARIABLE cursku REFCURSOR
EXECUTE pr_getcu(&item, :cursku) 
--Get the user input for item at this point

PRINT cursku
```